# Is it a personal style or a kind of expression tip to put a "made" immediately after "error"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This video is saying (https://youtu.be/yXJYRlxkfu4?t=320)

> This is incorrect. Well this is the most common error *made*.

Adding a "made" does not affect the meaning at all. I have no difficulty on understanding the meaning.

I just wonder is it a personal style or a kind of expression tip to put a "made" immediately after "error"?

Comment: This is an elision of "this is the most common error **that is** made" or "this is the most common error made **by people**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is the most common error which is made.

It is called "clause reduction", for example:
The car **which is** parked next to mine is very expensive.
The car **parked** next to mine is very expensive.

for further information about other forms, you can take a look at:
https://www.grammarbank.com/reduced-relative-clauses.html